# Subset dataframes stored in a list

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list containing 16 dataframes all of which have only two columns

```
DateTime    Value 
2009-05-31    100
2009-06-30    200
2009-07-31    300 
and so on
```

I want to subset all the dataframes in the list based on a date filter. I tried the following code but it did not work out

```
> c <- function(df) {
+ within(df, DateTime >= "2009-06-30")
+ }
> train_data <- lapply(my_data, c)
```

Am I missing out on something here ?

Thank You.

Comment: Try to transform your times into appropiate format, `lapply(d, function(x, y)  x[as.POSIXct(x$DateTime) > y, ], as.POSIXct("2009-06-30") )`. Beside your problem avoid to name functions or variables after internal functions (`c()`) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I found the answer

```
training_data <- lapply(my_data, subset, DateTime >= "2009-06-30")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming the Datetime columns in your data frames are formatted as Dates):

```
c <- function(df){
df[df$DateTime >= as.Date("2009-06-30"),]
}

train_data <- lapply(my_data, c)
```

Or if you want to use `with`:

```
c <- function(df){
with(df, df[DateTime >= "2009-06-30",])
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you make me understand the difference between your answer and what I posted in the question since the logic looks the same for both

Comment: I think it's your use of `within`. I always get confused between `within` and `with` so I am not the best person to explain it. I think `within` modifies the data.frame adding the elements evaluated in the expression. While `with` evaluates the expression in an environment created using the variables in the data frame. I edited the answer to include an implementation using `with`, see if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have a subset method:

```
new_df = subset(df, DateTime > "2009-06-30")
```

The output will be:

```
    DateTime Value
3 2009-07-31   300
```